# Getting a CSV cell full value in PHP

Tags: php, csv, import-csv

Am reading a CSV file using PHP, i get all the values for each row but some columns having long data displays something like this `9.21008E+15`
I don't know how to get the complete value which is suppose to be this `9210080000000000`

```
if (($handle = fopen("Test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $tb_row = "";
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $tb_row .= $data[$c].",";
    }
    $new_row = substr($tb_row, 0, -1);//removing the comma at the end of line...
    //explode and assign values then insert
    $each_col = explode(',', $new_row);
    $Device_state = $each_col[0];
    $udid = $each_col[8];
    $imsi = $each_col[9];
    $imei = $each_col[10];
    echo "$imsi || $imei"."<br />";
}
}
```

Comment: Don't open in in Excel?

Comment: PHP is not doing anything with that. Value already stored like E+15 in CSV may be you opened it in to excel and excel automatically replaced with E+15 try to convert that column in to Text in Excel.

Comment: What kind of nonsense is going on in that script anyway? fgetcsv gets the the columns of one row as an array. From that, you create a string, where you separate each value with a comma - only to then explode that at the comma again ... not only does that seem rather superfluous, but it creates potential for errors with column values that might themselves contain the column separator character.

Comment: @CBroe there wont be any comma delimiter, so its completely safe

Comment: Ok, so it is just “safe” nonsense then.

Comment: @CBroe shhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 0):

Adding a prefix to the cells having this issue solved the issue (')

Answer (score 0):

You need just convert it back into integer value

```
if (($handle = fopen("Test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $tb_row = "";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if (strpos($data[$c], 'E+'))
                $data[$c] = intval((float)$data[$c]);

            $tb_row .= $data[$c].",";
        }
        $new_row = substr($tb_row, 0, -1);//removing the comma at the end of line...
        //explode and assign values then insert
        $each_col = explode(',', $new_row);
        $Device_state = $each_col[0];
        $udid = $each_col[8];
        $imsi = $each_col[9];
        $imei = $each_col[10];
        echo "$imsi || $imei"."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are a genius your solution works well without having to worry about adding a prefix. Thanks

Comment: @PeterT if you are okay with the loss of precision this might include ...

Comment: @CBroe you are right, then i will have to stick with my answer

Comment: @CBroe can you give me an example?

Comment: @Neodan this was not actually a critique of your approach - if you already _get_ `9.21008E+15` from the CSV, then what you have shown is a valid way to get a “full number” from that again. The problem is that Excel might have thrown away significant digits already - there is no way to know any more, whether `9.21008E+15` was _originally_ `9210080000000000` - or maybe rather `9210080000000001` ...? Therefor what Peter posted as an answer, adding a quote character to the field value in Excel to begin with, is the proper way to handle _that_ situation.

Comment: @CBroe Oh yes, but then the problem is in the data source, not code. (-;

Comment: @Neodan yeah, I know. Just wanted to make sure Peter was aware what exactly he would be getting with this.